# Connected subgroups of $SL(2,C)$

Tags: lie-groups

Where can I find a list of all connected real Lie groups inside the 6-dimensional real Lie group $SL(2,C)$, up to conjugacy? How can one verify that a partial list is complete?

I found on wikipedia a [list of Lie subalgebras of so(1,3)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group#Subgroups_of_the_Lorentz_group), but it is not clear to me how to see which of these exponentiate to the double cover SL(2,C) of SO^+(1,3).

Comment: Easy exercise. Look for the possible Lie algebras. The 1-dimensional subalgebras are classified by Jordan normal form; there are two of them (diagonalizable and not). There is only one 2-dimensional subalgebra, the Borel subalgebra.

Comment: There are three classes of connected complex algebraic subgroups, up to conjugacy: the maximal torus $T$ consisting of all diagonal matrices, the unipotent subgroup $U$ consisting of upper triangular matrices with 1 on the diagonal, and the Borel subgroup $B=TU$ of all upper triangular matrices.

Comment: It's unclear if the question is about complex or real subgroups (the tag might suggest the second option).

Comment: The group is a 6-dimensional real Lie group. I am not only interested in its complex Lie subgroups.

Comment: Ok, I was thinking of the complex ones. Every real one lies in a complexification (by complexifying the Lie algebra), so you have a place to start from. The real forms of $SL(2,C)$ are $SO(3)$ and $SL(2,R)$.

Comment: Isn't SU(2) an aadditional real form of SL(2,C)?

Comment: @BenMcKay you don't only have real forms. Complex Lie subalgebras $h$ are those for which $h=ih$. "Purely real" are those for which $h\cap ih=0$ (and thus $h$ is a real form of $h\oplus ih$). But it can be otherwise (typically, when $h$ has dimension 3 and $h\cap ih$ has dimension 2). The general discussion is not so complicated but can be done by first discussing $h\cap ih$ and $h+ih$ (which are both complex subalgebras).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let me describe the Lie subalgebras.

Up to conjugation by $\mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbf{C})$, the complex subalgebras are $\{0\}$, the diagonal subalgebra, the upper unipotent subalgebra, the upper triangular subalgebra, and the whole $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbf{C})$. Their real dimension are 0, 2, 2, 4, 6 respectively.

The purely real subalgebras ($\mathfrak{h}$ such that $\mathfrak{h}\cap i\mathfrak{h}=\{0\}$) are real forms of these. There is $\{0\}$; in dimension 1 we have the upper unipotent real subalgebra, the subalgebra generated by the diagonal matrix $(e^{it},-e^{it})$, say for $0\le t<\pi$. In dimension 2 we have the upper triangular real Lie algebra. In dimension 3 we have both $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbf{R})$ and $\mathfrak{su}(2)$.

There is no subalgebra of real codimension 1. The remaining $\mathfrak{h}$ have dimension 3 or 4, and $\mathfrak{h}\cap i\mathfrak{h}$ has dimension 2; then $\mathfrak{h}+i\mathfrak{h}=\{0\}$ has dimension 4 or 6. the second case is not possible because $\mathfrak{h}$ would be non-solvable and only possible simple subalgebras are 3-dimensional, and are maximal sulalgebras. 
The remaining ones have codimension 1 in the upper triangular subalgebra: thus we get, up to conjugation, the (3-dimensional) subalgebra generated by upper unipotent matrices and the diagonal matrix $(e^{it},-e^{it})$, for $0\le t<2\pi$.

I guess this is comprehensive, I haven't 100% checked that there is no redundancy; anyway details are of exercise level (only using as a black box the classification of real simple Lie algebras up to dimension 6). In addition, they all exponentiate to closed Lie subgroups.

Comment: Does each of these Lie algebras produce a Lie subgroup of $SL(2,C)$, or do some of them only produce Lie subgroups of $SO^+(1,3)$?

Comment: I don't refer to $SO^+(1/3)$. The Lie subalgebras I listed exponentiate to analytic subgroups. Possibly you're asking whether they all exponentiate to closed subgroups, and the answer is indeed yes.